# How to change the Google Assistant command parameters at run time when we have hard-coded values in an array?

Tags: android, google-assistant, app-actions, voice-control

I have an array set in array.xml which are the possible commands:

```xml
<resources>
    <string-array name="completed_tasks_synonyms">
        <item>completed</item>
        <item>completed tasks</item>
        <item>finished</item>
        <item>finished tasks</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I also have this in my shortcuts.xml file which references the commands as a parameter for the OPEN_APP_FEATURE BII:

```xml
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="completed_tasks"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/label_completed"
        android:enabled="false"
        >
        <capability-binding android:key="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
            <parameter-binding
                android:key="feature"
                android:value="@array/completed_tasks_synonyms"
                />
        </capability-binding>
    </shortcut>
```

I want to change these array run time how can I do that because xml file cannot be change?